# Support package responsible for the stand by mode Logitech wirelles products

Tags: package-info

Good day. The distro Ubuntu contains a package(s) which allows switch the wireless keyboard and mouse Logitech MK 330 in the standby mode after 5 minutes of inactivity. Tell me what kind of package is?